# iPhone UITableViewCell with UIWebView inside: selection problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview

I have an UITableView and in every cell I add 3 custom subviews: label, webview and another label. The problem I am having is that when I tap a cell, instead of all the cell's background changing to blue, it only changes around the webview, but the webview still has a white background. it's very ugly. Is the any way of fixing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[theWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[theWebView setOpaque:NO];
```

Sorry, I answered my own question. In fact, a friend helped me with that one. Pasting it here in case anyone else needs it.

Cheers